# Android google maps single tap on marker for drag & drop

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, android-maps-v2

I have an application where the user can drag & drop a pin on the map. But in order to drag and drop the pin you have to hold it for a few seconds, right?

Is there a way to drag the pin as soon as the user taps on it? Thanks

P.S using Google Maps for Android API v2

Comment: Did you get the solution ?

Answer (score -1):

Drop the pin <==> Hide the pin??

You can do this, but you need to keep the reference of the pin that you have added in a variable. Do not simply add it, you need to store it to a variable then add this variable to the overlay. Later you can remove the required overlay, by simply calling remove() on that instance.